# How to set up manually a resolved dns record

Tags: dns

I'd like to manually and persistently set "goo" to be resolved to one of google.com server IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in /etc/hosts in the form:

```
   <ip>    <host>
```

You can find out the IP's from running `nslookup google.com`

For example, put this in /etc/hosts:

```
173.194.40.228    goo
```